# Error during SonarQube Scanner execution.The folder 'src' does not exist for 'SonarTest'

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I get the following error when I try to execute SonarQube Scanner as a part of Jenkins build:

[image]

Other configurations as follow：

[image]

The project in SVN：

[image]

The directory as follow：

[image]

Comment: You setup the options sonar.sources=src but your code is in SonarTest/src. Change to sonar.sources=SonarTest\src

Comment: After change to sonar.sources=SonarTest/src,everything is ok.Thanks very much!@Joao Vitorino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You setup the options sonar.sources=src but your code is in SonarTest/src.

Change to sonar.sources=SonarTest\src

[Access here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) to see the list of sonar paramaters.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but the issue was I copied the route directly from the file explorer, where it was given with backslashes, `\`.

So I changed `C:\Users\ ...` to `C:/Users/ ...` by replacing backslashes with common slashes, `/`, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows use / instead of \ for source path

Comment: Your answer seems to be same as the answer by "Bernardo Corengia", only less verbose.